# (C++/DirectX11) Something wrong in ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw() (or in my head)

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx

Using DirectX SDK which was included to Windows8 SDK.
Compile is success, but program stops in one place. Debugging showed error in this function:

```
    //ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext
    //IDXGISwapChain* swapChain
    //const float BackGround[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
        void DrawScene(){
            deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, BackGroung);

            deviceContext->Draw(3, 0); //<-this

            swapChain->Present(0, 0);
        }
```

While commenting this function everything goes OK. I think that I have some problems in this functions:

```
bool InitScene(){

    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_4_0", NULL, NULL, &vsBuffer, NULL);
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_4_0", NULL, NULL, &psBuffer, NULL);

    hr = device->CreateVertexShader(vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
    hr = device->CreatePixelShader(psBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), psBuffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

    Vertex v[] = {
        Vertex(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(&vertexBufferDesc));

    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 3;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData));
    vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;

    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &triangleVertexBuffer);

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset  = 0;

    deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 0, &triangleVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    hr = device->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout);

    deviceContext->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);
    deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Height = Height;
    viewport.Width = Width;

    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    return true;
}
```

Or here:

```
bool Init3D(){
    DXGI_MODE_DESC bufferDesc;

    ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));

    bufferDesc.Width = Width;
    bufferDesc.Height = Height;
    bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    bufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    bufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;

    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc = bufferDesc;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &swapChainDesc,
        &swapChain,
        &device,
        NULL,
        &deviceContext);

    ID3D11Texture2D *backBuffer;
    hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&backBuffer);

    hr = device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, NULL, &renderTargetView);
    backBuffer->Release();

    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetView, NULL);

    return true;

}
```

I'm perfect lamer and can't understand what's going wrong. Help me please.

Comment: Be sure to create your device with the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag. If you do, Direct3D should dump useful information in the output window if it crashes.

Comment: Turn on the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and make sure to test every function that returns an HRESULT for success or failure using the ``FAILED`` macro.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't set shaders to device context: `deviceContext->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0); deviceContext->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);`